# Is there a way to get the authentication from KeyCloak without password and without webAuthN

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect, keycloak-gatekeeper

I am currently working on a face recognition based login for an application and I want to provide authentication and authorisation for the user if his face is verified. Now Here's how the flow goes,

1. The user scans their face and the facial data is sent via API to the server to be verified.
2. Once the user is verified, then the user's username is given as a response.

Now how I can I get the authentication for the user, considering that I don't have the personal mail-ID of the user to perform webaAuthN.

Please help me... It really is important for me please..!

I tried getting the user information using OAuth by creating a public client who has access to querying the user information. Now that I got the user information, but I couldn't find how to get the password authentication of it.

Comment: There isn't an alternative approach that fits your case perfectly, but fortunately, Keycloak offers a high degree of flexibility within its code base. This allows you to devise a tailored solution that aligns with your specific requirements. I highly recommend pursuing an 'device binding' approach, as it seems well-suited for your situation.